Reading Fillable PDF in Laravel
I am trying to create a fillable form in the form of a PDF which will contain form data. The PDF file will be uploaded into a form on the website and the data will be read later.
I looked for several libraries but haven't found a suitable library for that. How can I read the contents of the textfield in this PDF?

have you tried https://github.com/mgufrone/pdf-to-html and then reading the html.
